# I'm having problems with null pointer exception and JFrames

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

This is my code: there is also a `JPanel` if you need that but I'm nearly certain that that the `JPanel` works. The problem I'm having is that my `JPanel` is not showing up on the `JFrame`. Thank you very much for your help.

```
package projectz;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ProjectZ extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    int scale = 2;
    int playerx = 0;
    int playery = 0;
    Backround back;
    JLayeredPane pane;



    public ProjectZ(){
        super("This game");
        setSize(250 * scale, 250 * scale);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        back = new Backround(playerx, playery);
        Component add;
        add = pane.add(back);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body       of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body   of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ProjectZ z;
        z = new ProjectZ();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're getting a NPE, the stack trace of that exception should be part of your question. And you should say which line in your code the NPE comes from. As it is, it just appears to me that you're not calling `pack()` after adding the component.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly (though this isn't your specific problem), you're instantiating your JFrame on the main thread. This will be a problem later when you come to implement the action events. Have `ProjectZ` implement `Runnable` instead, then use `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` in your main method to set it going. This will ensure you're running your user interface on the EWT not the main thread and that it will remain responsive.

Regards your actual problem, <s>difficult to tell without</s> the stack trace from the `NullPointerException` <s>(this</s> will tell you specifically what pointer is null and thus where the problem is<s>)</s> but regards seeing the component, if you `setVisible(true)` **after** you have added the component it will invalidate (then revalidate) the component hierarchy at that time and your `Background` `JPanel` component should then be drawn.

**EDIT:**
Others have rightly pointed out that the `JLayeredPane` object used has never been instantiated. Your stack trace will tell you this too.

Answer (score 2):

You havn't initialized `pane`. When you write `add = pane.add(back);` `pane` is null and that's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the issues @Smalltown2k mentions:

You have not initialized `pane`.
So, when you call `pane.add(back)`, `pane` is `null` and you get an NPE.